# How to re-trigger a stage in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a situation where in **2 Stages** in a `Jenkinsfile` I have to do the following things:

1. **Push a Docker image to artifactory**. This push is to a folder on artifactory where I cannot delete that pushed image easily (a lot of process is involved to get that deleted).
2. **Committing/ Merging changes to the master repo on GitLab**, within the stage itself (and not through an MR).

These 2 stages are connected to each other i.e. if Stage 1 has executed, then Stage 2 has to be executed.

So, you can understand these 2 stages are critical as in, they are making almost permanent changes to main folders and repos.

1. If Stage 1 fails (due to random flaky or connectivity issues), we want to re-run stage 1, and then continue with the job to stage 2
2. Also if Stage 1 has been executed successfully, but Stage 2 has failed, then I only want to run Stage 2 again.

Can someone suggest what can be done for this?

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422888/how-do-i-implement-a-retry-option-for-failed-stages-in-jenkins-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

For Declarative jobs, if you want to run stage 2 after stage 1 ran and the whole job failed, you can go to the specific build page and use the option "Restart From Stage". [from here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/):

> Once your Pipeline has completed, whether it succeeds or fails, you can go to the side panel for the run in the classic UI and click on "Restart from Stage".